# Flutter: using button to input a static text

Tags: flutter

I want to make list of button with a static text e.g(lorem, ipsum, etc) for a search bar, so when i hit the button it will input the text into textfield. can it be done in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `SeachDelegate` delegate

```
class CustomSearchHintDelegate extends SearchDelegate {
  CustomSearchHintDelegate({
    String hintText,
  }) : super(
    searchFieldLabel: hintText,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
  );

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) => Text("leading");

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) => Text("suggestions");

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {  // This is your list which comes from futurebuilder or streambuilder
    // BookModel bookModel = Provider.of(context);

    if (query.isNotEmpty)

      // return list of books which student wants to search
      return Consumer<BookModel>(
        builder: (_, bookModel, __) {
          return FutureBuilder(
              future: bookModel.searchOperation(query),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                // switch (snapshot.connectionState) /{
                // case ConnectionState.waiting:
                //   return Center(
                //     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                //   );
                //   break;
                // case ConnectionState.none:
                //   return Text("Something went wrong");
                //   break;
                // case ConnectionState.done:
                // case ConnectionState.active:
                if (!snapshot.hasData)
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? snapshot.data.length != 0
                        ? ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  final box = Hive.box("Student");
                                  snapshot.data[index].postedBy != box.get("ID")
                                      ? Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) => BookDetail(
                                              book: snapshot.data[index],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      : Navigator.push(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (con) =>
                                                MyPostedBookDetail(
                                              book: snapshot.data[index],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                },
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    snapshot.data[index].bookName.toString(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          )
                        : Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                              ),
                              Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  "No results found for '$query'",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                    : Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "No results found for '$query'",
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                // break;
              }
              // },
              );
        },
      );
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) => [];
}
```